Get list of tables
I recently migrated a solution from >NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 8.
Two blocks of code stopped working.
 Public Function GetTableList(vsDBName As String) As Collection

  Dim oSQLServer As Server
  Dim oServerConn As New ServerConnection
  Dim oTableList As New Collection
  Dim sDBName As String
  Dim oDatabase As Database

  oServerConn = oConnectionNet

  oSQLServer = New Server(oServerConn)
  oConnectionNet.Connect()
  sDBName = vsDBName
  If sDBName = "" Then
    sDBName = goADONetConn.Database
  End If

  oDatabase = oSQLServer.Databases.Item(sDBName)

  ' Limit the properties returned to just those that we use - very important for the performance
  oSQLServer.SetDefaultInitFields(GetType(Table), New String() {"Name", "IsSystemObject"})

  For Each oTable As Table In oDatabase.Tables
    If oTable.IsSystemObject = False Then
      oTableList.Add(oTable.Name, oTable.Name)
    End If
  Next
  oConnectionNet.Disconnect()
  Return oTableList

End Function`

The other block which stopped working:
 Private Sub cmdListDatabases_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdListDatabases.Click
  On Error GoTo HandleError

  Dim oSQLServer As  Server
  Dim oServerConn As New ServerConnection
  Dim csr As Cursor
  Dim dr As SqlDataReader
  Dim oDatabases As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

  txtStatus.Text = msComponentInfo 'reset Status message if there was an error before

  oServerConn.ServerInstance = cboServerNames.Text
  If rbLoginTypeSQL.Checked Then
    oServerConn.LoginSecure = False
    oServerConn.Login = txtUserName.Text
    oServerConn.Password = txtUserPassword.Text
  Else
    oServerConn.LoginSecure = True
  End If

  csr = Me.Cursor ' Save the old cursor
  Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor ' Display the waiting cursor

  oServerConn.Connect()
  If oServerConn.IsOpen = True Then
    oSQLServer = New Server(oServerConn)

    dr = oServerConn.ExecuteReader("exec sp_helpdb ")

    While dr.Read()
      oDatabases.Add(dr(0).ToString()) 'first column returned - "name"
    End While

    dr.Close()

    cboDatabase.Items.Clear()
    ' Limit the properties returned to just those that we use - very important for the performance
    oSQLServer.SetDefaultInitFields(GetType(Database), New String() {"Name", "DboLogin", "IsSystemObject"})`
......

In both of these the problem lines are to do with declaring a variable of Server type and then calling New Server
The Server type is not recognized.
In the old .NET Framework it was referring to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
I added imports:
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Imports zInteraction
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

and nuggets:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.2.2
System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.6
Microsoft.SQLServer.SQLManagementObjects 171.30.0
I tried to add nugget Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll but it fails to add due to incompatibility with .NET 8

Hungarian prefixes like o made sense back in the vb6 era, with poorer tooling and more dynamic typing. Thanks to the better tooling and type system for .NET, Microsoft (who originated them in the first place) has specifically recommended against hungarian prefixes in the language style guidelines for .NET.

Also, when you declare a variable with New, and then the very next use of the variable overwrites it with an assignment, so the newly allocated object is immediately thrown away, that makes us suspect you really don't know what you're doing at even a basic level (see oServerConn).

To be fair this code might have been written as much as 20 years ago.

Did this answer your question?

Yes, you are correct David. This code was written that long ago. I see it as a complement to Microsoft technology and how well it worked over such a long time.

The code was code was written 30 years ago using VB 6 and Hungarian notation by non-programmers. Uses millions of lines of code and it is difficult to redo. I see it as a complement to Microsoft technology and how well it worked over such a long time. No need for comments of "that makes us suspect you really don't know what you're doing at even a basic level".

The only NuGet package you need for this is the latest
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects" Version="171.30.0" />
</ItemGroup>

This worked for me (C# obviously), but it will work the same in VB.NET.
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;


using var con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=tempdb;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true");
var sc = new ServerConnection(con);
var s = new Server(sc);

Console.WriteLine("Server Created");

You're jumping up quite a number of versions of SMO here, so you should expect some small breaking changes.

Isn't microsoft.data.sqlclient kinda deprecated?

No.  You're thinking of System.Data.SqlClient.  Switching from building on System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is one of the breaking changes SMO made a couple of years ago.
Basically as part of .NET Framework, moving System.Data.SqlClient forward became increasingly difficult.  So all new work shifted to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient supports all of the modern Entra ID authentication flows.

Thanks, i thought it was the other way around!
